# Updating several tables column value at once in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, datatables

I have within a **database** several tables where they all have **username** column. I would like to update one **username** and naturally I should update it in all tables.

I have this working solution:

```
UPDATE `user`, 
       `user_images`, 
       `user_comments` 
SET `user`.`username` = 'new_name', 
    `user_images`.`username` = 'new_name', 
    `user_comments`.`username` = 'new_name'
WHERE `user`.`username` = 'old_name' 
AND `user_images`.`username` = 'old_name' 
AND `user_comments`.`username` = 'old_name'
```

I am hoping for a better **query** that can do the same action, as if table numbers got increased, do I really need to do this in 100 lines?

Comment: Why store username in more than 1 table ? It should be enough to only store it in the table `user`.

Comment: with the logic I've used in for example **profile page** I would fetch from image table where ``username = current_logged_in_username`` @Luuk

Comment: I would use a unique id (i.e. `user_id`) in all tables. When doing that you only need to change 1 table when the name changes. (and the `user_id` should never change)

Comment: Please research/read on rdbms basic design and data normalization tutorials. That'll help you understand why duplicating the same data in multiple tables is bad!!!!

Comment: Stored procedure, cursor by INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, dynamic SQL.

Comment: I actually didn't look of things with this logic of unique id which is actually better I admit, and I will start applying this in later projects then! thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds painful if you have to update each table. I would suggest using a stored procedure to finish the tedious job. Fisrt of all , make a table(named tablelist) which list all the tablename you would like to update. Then call the procedure  by providing the two parameters where the o_name is the name you would like to change and the n_name is the new name to be changed into.

```
delimiter //
 drop procedure if exists update_name//
 create procedure update_name (o_name varchar(30),n_name varchar(30))
 begin
declare t_name varchar(30);
declare done bool default false;
declare csr cursor for select tablename from tablelist;
declare continue handler for not found set done=true;

open csr;
lp: loop
fetch csr into t_name;
if done=true then
leave lp;
end if;

set @prep=concat('update ',t_name,' set `username`= "',n_name,'" where `username`= "',o_name,'";'); 
prepare prep_stat  from @prep;
execute prep_stat;
deallocate prepare prep_stat;

  end loop lp;

close csr; 
 
end//
delimiter ;
```

The following call will change the name from john(case insensitive) to Xero in all tables listed in the tablelist table.

```
call update_name('John','Xero');
```